# Background imaage css

Tags: css

i wanted to ask why my picture is not getting inside the first container when i set it as background image.

did i made the path wrong? [image]

this is so far the code i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="first-image">
      <h1>Delije</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



.first-image {
  background-image: url(./images\pattern.jpeg);
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS should be like this:

```
.first-image {
  background-image: url(images/pattern.jpeg);
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

The forward slash is the correct form of the addressing.

Answer (score 1):

The image url needs to be a string:

`background-image: url('./images/pattern.jpeg');`

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect

```
url(./images\pattern.jpeg)
```

You have one `/` and then `\`

Answer (score 0):

The path is incorrect, your code should be this instead.

```
.first-image {
background-image: url('images/pattern.jpeg');
border: 2px solid red;
}
```